# Call script from Windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line-arguments, execution, dm-script

Is it possible to call a script in Digital Micrograph from the Windows command line? I cannot seem to find information on command line options, if any are available, for DM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible **for GMS version 2 or lower.** There are no command-line parameters for script-launch in DigitalMicrograph.

However, if you want to run a script automatically on start-up of DM, you can do this by installing a script as plugin (.gtk file).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! That's what I was afraid of. I am trying to automate some scripts on the microscope PC, initiated by another application, so DM is already open.

Comment: @AWag you might be able to do it the other way around: Have a DM script run an executable and wait for it to return. Or (more ugly) have a DM script wait for a specific file to exist in a folder as a "trigger" signal. The file may contain info you want to transfer...

Comment: The wait for file option may work for me. Is it possible to do this in the background (without locking up DM?) This may still be acceptable if I to use the DM installation on the support PC. If not too complicated and you're willing, could you provide a snippet to demonstrate the approach you would take? Thanks!

Comment: @AWag I have now done so in a [separate posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28536623/how-can-one-synchronize-an-external-application-with-a-digitalmicrograph-script/28536929#28536929).

Answer (score 1):

From **GMS 3.0.1** onward, there is an optional start-up parameter for the application.

You can type (in the command prompt):

> `DigitalMicrograph.exe /ef "test.s"`
>
> to launch the script `test.s` within the application.

Similar, you can type things like

> `DigitalMicrograph.exe /es "scriptcommand"`
>
> to directly execute the script-line `scriptcommand` within the application.

Unfortunately, earlier version of GMS do not have this option.

Note: When you call DigitalMicrograph.exe while the application is already running, it will *not* start the program again but instead activate the already running application. Therefore this can be used to launch a script in an already running application.

---

---

This also opens a nice way to run DM-scripts from a different editor like NotePad++.

In **NotePad++** you can configure a "run" command.
If you press **F5** you specify a command to be called. So to have this run a DM script, use a line like the following:

```
"C:\Program Files\Gatan\DigitalMicrograph.exe" /ef "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

You can then execute a script writtin within NotePad++ simply by  selecting this run.