# How can one synchronize an external application with a DigitalMicrograph script?

Tags: events, synchronization, external, dm-script

> This question has been inspired by the question ['Call script from command line'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28495288/call-script-from-command-line).

#### How can one write a script which acts on 'trigger events' in an application *other* than DigitalMicrograph?

i.e. some script functionality should be triggered by an external application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scripting language does not offer many 'external' interfaces in its current state. It is possible to *call out* to an external process with the command `LaunchExternalProcess` and wait for the process to complete, but there is no straight-forward way for an external process to *call in*, i.e. to start a script-action within DigitalMicrograph.

However, it is possible to work around that issue by using the system's file-system as a message queue. To do this, have a script running in the background which regularly checks if a certain file exists, and have the *external* application create such a file when it wants to trigger a scripting-action in DigitalMicrograph. The file content - if it is a simple text file - can also be used to transport information between the two applications.

Here is an example script which will wait until the file `Trigger.txt` appears in the root folder. The check is performed every 10seconds.

```
class WaitForExternal
{
    string triggerFilePath
    number taskID
    void WaitOnTrigger( object self )
    {
        if ( DoesFileExist( triggerFilePath ) )
        {
            Result( GetTime(1) + ": Triggered! Now act..." )
            If ( TwoButtonDialog( "Do you want to reset the trigger?", "Reset", "Stop" ) )
            {
                DeleteFile( triggerFilePath )
            }
            else
            {
                RemoveMainThreadTask( taskID )
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Result( GetTime(1) + ": not yet\n" )
        }
    }

    object Init( object self, string triggerPath, number waitSec ) 
    { 
        triggerFilePath = triggerPath
        taskID = self.AddMainThreadPeriodicTask( "WaitOnTrigger", waitSec )
        return self
    }
}

// Main script
{
    string triggerPath = "C:\\Trigger.txt"
    number pollingWait = 10
    Alloc(WaitForExternal).Init( triggerPath, pollingWait )
}
```

Note that the periodic task waits idle in the background without interfering with the CPU, but the actual check is then performed on the main thread.

Comment: In extension: From GMS 3.0.1 onward, there is also the option to "start" a script in DigitalMicrograph via a command-line parameter for DigitalMicrograph.exe. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33759124/1302888)